# Antiderivative of 3/x

Tags: integration

The equation is $$\frac{1}{5} - \frac{3}{x},$$ rewritten as $$\frac{1}{5} - 3x^{-1}.$$ So the anti-derivative should  be $$\frac{1}{5}x - 3\frac{x^0}{0} + C,$$ which doesn't exist. Can anyone help?

Comment: Remember that the rule of the anti-derivative of $x^n$ _doesn't work_ for $n = -1$?  What is the anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: Try to go to the FAQ section and read quickly there the directions to write properly mathematics in this site with LaTeX. It may well be you're seeing something on your paper nad writing something else here, and that's why you keep on getting a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}= \ln x$

Comment: So would it be 3x*ln x?

Comment: Your second term can be written as $3 \cdot \frac{1}{x}$.  What is the rule for integrating a constant times a function?

Comment: No. $\int \frac{3}{x}dx=3\int \frac{1}{x}dx=3\ln x$

Comment: cf(x) = cf'(x)? So it would be 3*ln x? Edit: nvm, ty adam

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting a wrong answer online: (1/5)x - 3*ln x + C, but is this correct?

Comment: @Foxic yes, it is

Comment: @Foxic: Not quite, actually. The antiderivative of $\frac1x$ is actually $\ln|x|$, so you'll replace $\ln x$ with $\ln|x|$ in your expression. Otherwise, yes, that's correct.